# How to add elements together in nested list?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop, nested-lists

I am trying to add together the last and first names of people in a nested list from a .csv file. My data looks like this:
[Picture of data spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUwGV.png)

My list, peopleNames, has this current output:

```
[['Barreuther', 'Mark', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['Demaio', 'Daniel', 'Certo', 'Catherine', 'Frankel', 'Stewart', 'Levesque', 'Aime', 'Mahan', 'Eric J.', 'Rosiene', ' Pe', 'Haruta', 'Mako E.', '', '']... many more lists]
```

I would like to add the two strings that are next to each other together. Ex. [['Barreuther Mark']]. I have tried the following code:

```
def getInfo():
"""Open csv, read it, get nested list, separate names and schools, return two lists"""

#
with open("CT_schools.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = []
    #start for
    for row in reader:
        data.append(row)               
    #end for

    schoolNames = []
    peopleNames = []

    #start for
    for i in range(len(data)):
        schoolNames.append(data[i][0])
        peopleNames.append(data[i][1:])
    #end for

    index = 0
    name = 0
    NewpeopleNames = []
    #start while
    while index < len(peopleNames):
        for i in range(len(peopleNames)):
            fullName = peopleNames[index][i] + " " + peopleNames[index][i+1]
        NewpeopleNames.append(fullName)
        index = index + 1
        name = name + 2
```

To which I get the following output:

[' ', ' Pe Haruta', 'Ronald Golbazi', 'Christoph Raskin', ' ', ' ', 'Barry Oliver', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'Douglad M. ']

I then replaced the while loop with a nested for-loop:

```
#start nested for
    for index in range(len(peopleNames)):
        for name in range(len(peopleNames[index])):
            fullName = peopleNames[index][name] + peopleNames[index][name + 1]
```

I then get an error saying that it's out of the list's index. Do you think someone could try to point me in the right direction? Much appreciated!

Comment: please read about [mre]. your code is missing definition of `peopleNames` for example. We can copy-paste and run your code. Also an example of your data would be in place

Comment: @Tomerikoo Is this better?

Comment: You want to change the `for` loop to be `for name in range(0, len(peopleNames[index])-1, 2)`. And indent your `append` line to be inside the loop or you will just add the last name for each row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested for loop is the naive solution (if you don't the complexity of the code).

I would suggested to first filter out all the empty values from the list and only then I quote "add the two strings that are next to each other together".

```
NewPeopleNames = list()
for sub_list in peopleNames:
    tmp_list = list()
    filtered_list = list(filter(None, sub_list))
    for i in range(0, len(filtered_list), 2):
        if i+1 >= len(filtered_list):
            print('There is no last name for \'{0}\''.format(filtered_list[i]))
            continue
        tmp_list.append('{0} {1}'.format(filtered_list[i], filtered_list[i+1]))
    NewPeopleNames.append(tmp_list)
```

*Please note, there is a bit of "protection" from odd list size (first name and no last name).*

You can modified the print line to append just the name (filtered_list[i]) to the NewPeopleNames list.

Comment: Thank you! My next question is, how would I be able to get that list into nested lists like my original peopleNames was?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Can you add an output example.

Comment: Each nested list that was in my original peopleNames list had an associate school. (See output in original question). The code that you gave me gives me all the names compiled into 1 list. I would like to try to get the names back in their respectable nested list.

Ex. 'code' [['Barreuther Mark'],[]... other nested lists]

Comment: I modified the code.
Please have a second look on the new variable *tmp_list* usage.